# What happens to gold under immense pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, material-science, metals

What would happen to gold if you put it under immense atmospheric pressures?

For example 2M atmospheres.

Comment: Is that "2m" supposed to be 2 million?

Comment: Note that, as you take this to the extreme, *how* you put it under that pressure starts to matter.  Pressure doesn't just come from nowhere, you have to have something else applying that pressure.  For example, put steel into a diamond anvil cell and it may deform of move around.  Put steel under 2 million atmospheres of hydrogen, and you'll see hydrogen embrittlement as the hydrogen literally diffuses into the steel.

Comment: Your question is rather vague.  What kind of result are you expecting to find?

Answer (score 2):

Gold will compress to about half of its volume at atmospheric pressure if you compress it to 2 million atmospheres at room temperature, which is something that I'm sure has been done with diamond anvil cells. For many metals, the atomic lattice will also undergo structural phase transitions from one lattice type to another at certain pressures, but I don't believe that there are any such structural transitions in room-temperature gold up to 2 million atmospheres. The face-centered cubic (fcc) lattice of gold remains fcc all the way up to 2 million atmospheres. Also, the compression of gold up to this pressure is completely reversible. If the pressure is released from 2 million atmospheres, the gold lattice will relax back to its original atomic spacing.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that gold will remain gold and do not go into nuclear fusion. However I am not saying that it is impossible.

You may have heard of neutron stars and black holes, when the matter is under immense pressure the electrons around the nucleus could not withstand it and they fall into the nucleus and convert everything in a giant neutronic mass. Further if the pressure is too much then the neutrons can not withstand it and they collapsed into a singularity known as black hole.

chances that the gold will follow the neutron star route is larger than the nuclear fusion because the process is endothermic and in order to get the fusion you need to give the energy in addition to the pressure (i.e. heat the gold to an appreciably large temperature). Even in this case the fused atom will be very short lived and will decay very soon.